# Why is this linear transformation one-to-one and onto?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given this matrix $A$, and letting $T(x) = Ax$ be the linear transformation defined by multiplication by $A$.

$$A=\left( \begin{array}{c} 1 & -3 \\ -2 & 5\end{array}\right)$$

I let $Ax = 0$, and reduced it to this matrix:

$$A=\left( \begin{array}{c} 1 & -3 & 0\\ 0 & -1 & 0\end{array}\right)$$

Since letting $T(x) = 0$, and having only the trivial solution, shouldn't it be just one-to-one?

Why is it both one-to-one and onto?

Comment: I changed the title and statement so that it calls objects what they are. Check it to see if it expresses what you wanted.

Comment: @EnjoysMath It is one-to-one.  The determinant is non-zero.

Comment: $\det A = -1 \neq 0$, so $A$ is invertible.  This implies $T$ is bijective.

Comment: You can row reduce further and get rid of the $-3$.

Comment: The $1$ on your second row should be a $-1$.

Comment: @muros It is true you have, so far, proved only it is one-to-one. But you can also prove, using additional arguments, that $T$ is also onto. For this you should show the equation $T(x)=b$ has a solution in $x$ for every vector $b$. This would be to prove directly that it is onto. Alternatively, there are theorems that tell you that if an *automorphism* (linear $T:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ is one-to-one then it is automatically onto).

Comment: @ABC Please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).

Answer (score 1):

The determinant is nonzero, by the Invertible Matrix Theorem, every input has exactly one output and every output has exactly one input where there is a one-to-one correspondence